# Providing multiple dense vectors to Elasticsearch script params

Tags: python, elasticsearch, knn

I'm using the kNN functionality in Elastic to retrieve the nearest neighbors given a certain vector. However, in contrast with searches based on `terms` in the query body, I can't figure out how to do a single search request using multiple vectors.

Using the Python `elasticsearch` library I can do the following simple query while providing multiple ids to search in batch:

```py
query_body = {
            "terms": {
                "transaction_id": id_list  # <--- this is a list with multiple ids
            }
        }
    
    
search_results = client.search(index=index, query=query_body)
```

However, when I am doing a kNN query, I can only do the following:

```py
query_body = {
        "script_score": {
            "min_score": 0.80,
            "query": {"match_all": {}},
            "script": {
                "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'vector') + 1.0",
                "params": {"query_vector": query_vector},
            },
        }
    }

search_results = client.search(index=index, query=query_body)
```

The above code only retrieves the neighbours for one vector at a time. So if I have 10 vectors that I retrieve by id using the first code snippet, I have to sequentially feed them into the second snippet one by one. Is there not a way to provide multiple vectors to the `"params": {"query_vector" : <multiple_vectors_here>}`?

Ideally, I would like to chain the calls to Elastic in one operation, but I'm also not sure if that is possible (for example with [Multi search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently exact brute force KNN not support multipul query vector. You can read same [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/run-multi-vectors-knn-search/299958) on discuss.elastic site.

You can use Approximate KNN search with `should` cluase as shown [here](https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/k-NN/issues/221).

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. Thanks for linking the discussion!